# Springboot REST API returning 404 when deployed in Jboss EAP.7.1.0

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http-status-code-404, jboss7.x

I have created a simple Springboot REST api, which is working fine when deployed in Tomacat container but returning 404 message when deployed in Jboss EAP 7.1.0. Need help to resolve this problem.

Below are the classes i wrote along with pom.xml and application.properties

SpringRestApiApplication.java

```
package com.test.spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringRestApiApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

RestExample.java

```
package com.test.spring.web.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class RestExample {
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String HelloWorldAPI() {
        return "Hello World!";
        
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>       
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringRestAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SpringRestAPI</name>
    <description>Rest API Test Example</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>               
    </properties>
        
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>            
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
              <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>              
              <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>rest-api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.servlet-path=/*
```

Comment: Do you have a class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` in your application?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, After changing Spring Boot version to 2.1.5.RELEASE and also extending my main class (SpringRestApiApplication) with SprringBootServletInitializer, i am able to hit the end point (.../rest-api/test/hello)  only if i added rest-api in the url; for this url .../test/hello its returning 404

Answer (score 1):

You are using 7.1.0 right. Remove this and try `server.servlet-path=/*`